# php wrong result sort array by date

Tags: php, arrays, date

I'm sorting an array as:

```
function date_compare($a, $b)
{
    $t1 = strtotime($a['date']);
    $t2 = strtotime($b['date']);
    return $t1 - $t2;
}    
usort($array, 'date_compare');
```

However, as you can see the output below, dates are not sorted. Any idea why? Thanks

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 16870
            [date] => Tue, 22 Mar 2011 13:12:19 +1100
            [bar] => Foo
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 16871
            [bar] => foo
            [date] => Mon, 21 Mar 2011 23:06:32 -0500 (CDT)
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 16872
            [bar] => foo
            [date] => Tue, 22 Mar 2011 00:37:01 -0500 (CDT)
        )
}
```

Comment: I 'd guess that the dates are definitely sorted, but that `strtotime` doesn't return what you expect it to return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the dates are being sorted properly. You may want to do something like:

```
foreach ($dates as $i => $date)
{
  $dates[$i]['ts'] = strtotime($date['date']);
  $dates[$i]['date'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $dates[$i]['ts']);
}

usort($dates, function($a, $b) { return $a['ts'] - $b['ts']; });
```

Here I'm creating a `ts` property for each date so `strtotime()` doesn't need to be called twice per sort comparison. Second, I'm changing the date to be in the local timezone. You can adjust the format string as you want.

Alternatively, you could just `unset()` the `date` component of the array and call `date()` directly on the `ts` component when you want to print it.

Answer (score 4):

They're sorted just fine if you take the timezone into account, which `strtotime` does.

Comment: That's totally right. I didn't realize that. What would be a good way to remove the timezone from it?

Comment: Yea, was just gonna say it could be this. Tested and verified this is what its doing.